# Reading table rows with EOSJS

Tags: action, table, javascript, return, eosjs

Is there a way to receive the return output of an action with EOSJS? Say for example I have an action that reads columns from a table, sums a row and returns the result. How would I structure the function in C++ so that it returns the result, and how would I process the result in an EOSJS call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several ways to retrieve data from eos chain as i know. They differs a lot, so you should find a better one for you case.

**#1. Get from table**
As you noted there is `getTableRows` method in `eosjs` lib, and by default it returns packed response. You can pass option `json: true` to instruct library to unpack response for you.

```
eos.getTableRows({
    code:'CONTRACT_NAME',
    scope:'SCOPE_ACCOUNT (Normally contract)',
    table:'TABLE_NAME',
    json: true,
}).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

You can find other available options in json format [definition](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api/blob/0f0df9c8079b6532da497946203afb80b4fc940b/src/api/v1/chain.json#L108)

**#2. Read execution logs**
You can log some valuable info to "console" when your action is executed. Then to read those logs call `getActions` method from `eosjs` lib. It return a list of actions for specific account. See json [definition](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api/blob/0f0df9c8079b6532da497946203afb80b4fc940b/src/api/v1/history.json#L2) for more info.

```
this.eos.getActions('CONTRACT_NAME').then(...)
```

Note #1: Make sure that node you query from is running with **history_api_plugin** and `filter_on_accounts` option in config file respect your CONTRACT_NAME.

Note #2: Api returns every action that somehow belongs to provided account. So you need to filter them to find interesting one (use `transaction_id` received when transaction submitted).

There also a possible ways using mongodb plugin, but i can't provide any more info on this.

Comment: Thank you! Just discovered the `json:true` last night and was just writing an answer now. Yours is much better though, I'll make it the official answer now.